# dynamic tableview inside custom tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to create a tableview with custom cells that each one holds a tableview.
I want to show the inner tableview just when it have some data (most of the time it's empty). I've managed to display the cells but can't display their tableview if it's populated with data.

The problem also is that the cell height needs to be dynamic according to the amount of data to display.

The cell code:

```
class feedViewCell: UITableViewCell , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var feedCellImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var feedCellUserName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var feedCellDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var feedCellComments: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var cardView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var repliesTableView: UITableView!

var repliesArray:[Reply] = []

@IBAction func addComment(sender: AnyObject) {
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    var nib = UINib(nibName: "feedComment", bundle: nil)
    repliesTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "commentCell")
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    cardSetup()
}

func cardSetup() {
    cardView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-0.2, 0.2)
    cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return repliesArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = repliesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CommentFeedCell
    cell.commentCellUserName.text = repliesArray[indexPath.row].userName

    return cell
}
```

}

And the Main controller code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var comment = comments[indexPath.row]
    let cell: feedViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as feedViewCell
    cell.feedCellUserName.text = comment.userName
    cell.feedCellImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.feedCellComments.text = "\(comment.replies.count) COMMENTS"
    cell.repliesArray = comment.replies

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyy"
    cell.feedCellDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    if cell.repliesArray.count > 0 {
        cell.repliesTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    cell.repliesTableView.reloadData()

    return cell

}
```

How to show the inner tableview only in cells which have comments (and hiding the tableview in cells with 0 comments)?

Comment: Where are you setting dataSource for the repliesTableView?

Comment: The feedCell, which is the tableviewcell where the repliesTableView sits. I've tried first to connect to file's owner but it didn't worked so I've connected to the tableViewCell

Comment: In `feedCell` if you set a breakpoint at `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` , is that breakpoint hit when you run the program and the feedCells load?

Answer (score -1):

Call super in layoutSubviews and let us know what happens.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    cardSetup()
}
```

Comment: Downvoter explain yourself. The cell won't layout it subviews unless this method is called on super. It's a completely valid reason why its subview (the tableview) wouldn't appear.

Comment: I've add the super.layoutSubviews() but nothing happend